Unable to fit ANN to "simple" dataset?
I am really struggling of modeling a dataset that I acquired by doing experiments. Concretely, those are time series (online) data of measurements and the objectives are kinetic parameters that I fitted over each discrete time span (1h) of a chemical reaction.
I thought, that this would be a rather straightforward modeling task as things like this are published. However, for another chemical reaction. Am I doing something wrong?
So Var1 is one measurement. Var2 is the derivative of the measurement Var1 in the same time point. Var3 is another measurement. And Var4 the derivative of Var3 in this timepoint.
For this 11 experiments, 5 parameters were varied. The first 9 were planned as a latin hypercube design, therefore they should cover the experimental design space. My goal is to have a model of the kinetic parameters within this design space, therefore I always use the time series data of whole experiments to validate (e.g. experiment 10 and 11 as test dataset). However, I never achieved a nrmse of below 0.32 or so, unfortunately far too high.
In the following I will give you my dataset and the code I used. Any help is really really appreciated.



Var1
Var2
Var3
Var4
Obj1
Obj2
Exp




362.5236061
-0.07435406
864530.2255
3682.064903
0.003213373
0.00428076
1


359.7557849
-0.025538678
736590.687
-1075.97495
0.003263493
0.001824691
1


358.4991647
-0.017450826
691352.2705
-588.4522644
0.003275051
0.000967166
1


357.6539991
-0.010385667
661583.842
-303.3271618
0.003279432
0.000558512
1


357.0186877
-0.008255159
640921.1745
-194.7817104
0.003281502
0.000336697
1


356.5327836
-0.005731424
626451.1975
-198.922334
0.003282606
0.000207903
1


356.1503876
-0.003917789
615852.341
-94.75128942
0.00328324
0.000130188
1


355.8705829
-0.004881314
608682.1075
-101.6350643
0.00328363
8.21961E-05
1


355.64497
-0.003110438
603802.061
-160.5375622
0.003283885
5.21238E-05
1


355.4639077
-0.001994076
600991.2295
-135.4780436
0.003283367
3.4352E-05
1


356.5001926
-0.17556667
19813.98608
-115.8315456
0.005954796
0.060327557
2


354.7419647
-0.010554267
18572.43765
-15.1086585
0.019552834
0.002063382
2


354.5410356
0.004333489
18395.97176
3.58709367
0.019797517
0.000207129
2


354.4705883
0.003261012
18328.458
0.260837045
0.019477993
0.000139907
2


354.4471981
-0.000602105
18251.73567
-5.069623077
0.01871281
0.000274773
2


354.3714636
-0.002022128
18129.30001
-7.523852436
0.015549203
0.000622012
2


354.3472383
-0.005895534
18006.22191
-4.295397602
0.007628973
0.001178864
2


354.3640378
-8.50794E-05
17989.67701
0.778188728
0.003754402
0.001628867
2


354.3513409
-0.002118818
17925.92188
-0.650045175
0.003502226
0.002346723
2


354.3589349
0.000630516
17827.10342
-7.597788125
0.006913801
0.005766069
2


358.5681349
-0.137364094
1417431.912
5475.904179
0.002386724
0.021356606
3


354.8548339
-0.025447599
1433291.357
-501.5377722
0.002640114
0.008975807
3


353.9699445
-0.006276057
1399737.379
-532.2281408
0.002680502
0.005460136
3


353.5810013
-0.004313607
1353541.897
-762.2193935
0.002694162
0.003776971
3


353.4113006
-0.002831483
1301753.769
-706.8966195
0.002700392
0.002793216
3


353.2983542
-0.001158295
1265871.981
-267.6625715
0.002703748
0.002151943
3


353.2363759
-0.000551958
1241390.818
-382.8823426
0.002705757
0.001704076
3


353.2065872
0.000162355
1221418.773
-296.6559633
0.002707054
0.001376099
3


353.1937995
0.001616808
1203285.87
-232.2787229
0.002707935
0.001127516
3


353.2084878
-0.001193965
1190199.653
-200.9625616
0.002708213
0.000935661
3


355.2607728
-0.06549112
428587.8465
-2711.557955
0.012031713
0.03116071
4


353.3381078
-0.009040949
384908.2786
-206.9562854
0.013995544
0.010595812
4


353.0920602
-0.00379961
373721.5884
-179.0413032
0.014326813
0.005225963
4


352.9546877
-6.51482E-05
362706.5069
-157.7725837
0.014457437
0.002872939
4


352.8822109
-0.000143343
351736.6721
-170.2497273
0.014639103
0.001475783
4


352.8337743
-0.001013735
340706.7499
-123.3086883
0.014273536
0.001056589
4


352.7950174
0.000967585
331108.5719
-150.6339713
0.012875985
0.001497312
4


352.7563879
-0.004171553
323477.3783
-105.4632373
0.009130093
0.002423721
4


352.7234116
-0.000953956
317607.4407
-61.80249755
0.005652496
0.003252655
4


352.6931665
-0.003292633
312764.6088
-72.34633083
0.007929598
0.006297833
4


354.9099373
-0.064489957
59228.19355
-34.66483122
0.001684243
0.036859361
5


354.2851724
-0.002153598
52131.66616
-51.55228823
0.002411635
0.009851665
5


354.0427482
-0.002159137
50261.48344
-42.90076455
0.002465327
0.00553448
5


353.9577172
0.002098824
48680.74202
-6.426667598
0.00248066
0.00368941
5


353.9119757
-0.003922988
47473.56546
-15.18383365
0.002487109
0.002667652
5


353.8844547
0.002037318
46285.15086
-16.07529822
0.002490416
0.002022766
5


353.8668704
0.002827529
45195.30073
-16.9351117
0.002492325
0.001582153
5


353.8736059
0.000766154
44332.88679
2.868984782
0.002493515
0.001264637
5


353.8714587
-0.000399668
43442.88279
-27.44262532
0.002494291
0.001026988
5


353.8811012
0.000340549
42578.14691
-14.50903174
0.002494568
0.000848156
5


360.3026948
-0.251951117
43670.5716
-660.0508025
0.009775108
0.005432146
6


355.0732977
-0.034455945
33782.5738
-51.43104459
0.010053779
0.010858642
6


353.9743005
-0.005542832
31973.23072
-18.1358307
0.013353613
0.039248918
6


353.5721478
-0.003969615
31006.18569
-14.10908244
0.002593539
0.069104028
6


353.3813316
-0.003120327
30241.61401
-10.49708263
0.002215485
0.00242661
6


353.2839077
0.001319001
29525.55267
-10.14276558
0.001530724
0.001549412
6


353.2021507
-0.000136787
28906.70627
-4.715726494
0.001462896
0.00147424
6


353.2302605
0.000632397
28429.48104
-9.911424404
0.00166997
0.001680189
6


353.1941322
-0.001467403
27921.07523
-7.234047644
0.002364115
0.002377429
6


353.1655174
-0.00474924
27495.34164
-5.85646953
0.00584086
0.005873753
6


362.8602921
-0.068471633
660881.783
-4939.335052
0.00689823
0.001411131
7


357.3865145
-0.068253677
502808.1665
-889.3749967
0.0069007
0.001716404
7


354.6802533
-0.029288028
477658.981
-168.2014051
0.006904063
0.002104605
7


353.5374195
-0.01293931
472322.0689
31.03798463
0.006908756
0.002607386
7


353.0292191
-0.00594159
470954.9579
-25.26509872
0.006915607
0.003274263
7


352.7288209
-0.004889982
471085.8684
15.12284176
0.006926112
0.004187288
7


352.5306925
-0.004590968
471796.343
10.16912988
0.006943328
0.005493162
7


352.4127263
-0.000399474
472833.1245
38.27497096
0.006974109
0.007482901
7


352.3050464
-0.002530674
474542.7729
8.638551421
0.007033087
0.010827543
7


352.2001627
-1.2048E-05
475979.5012
0.169241821
0.007224841
0.017501587
7


361.7847108
-0.009007496
1153715.769
-6689.862256
0.001742378
0.017626545
8


360.7925504
-0.010893197
1050694.028
-797.7488604
0.002226841
0.003056319
8


360.1930918
-0.008834233
1011533.294
-567.8726227
0.00224652
0.001467164
8


359.6481841
-0.007971995
977920.9475
-620.7601626
0.002251805
0.000840495
8


359.1329689
-0.007196525
948079.119
-399.1770228
0.002253953
0.00052013
8


358.6224796
-0.008396382
919272.018
-301.0694647
0.002255019
0.00033549
8


358.1804212
-0.007504499
894862.8745
-297.3461779
0.002255614
0.000221761
8


357.7788613
-0.005287814
872575.8815
-229.7678176
0.002255972
0.000148833
8


357.4293511
-0.006047173
853865.9935
-327.1636538
0.002256198
0.000100853
8


357.1290048
-0.0048727
838230.665
-192.8233643
0.002256036
6.99439E-05
8


365.3614792
0.002578826
44113.43769
-43.16217324
0.000398913
0.001770589
9


365.2331841
-2.34215E-05
40861.15028
-52.40644436
0.000399046
0.002032988
9


365.1497403
-0.0019704
37532.09081
-62.30731611
0.000399248
0.002377068
9


365.007455
-0.000260381
33650.23947
-70.26406207
0.000399571
0.002847905
9


364.8196841
-0.004124577
29738.58254
-59.4030107
0.000400135
0.003531402
9


364.5005972
-0.009202236
26285.55899
-51.59209241
0.00040126
0.004614346
9


364.0713779
-0.010897665
23471.97984
-48.61360046
0.000404049
0.006596842
9


363.5073076
-0.007957968
21186.9511
-29.74440468
0.000414847
0.011468264
9


362.8063233
-0.008804873
19258.75186
-23.06773732
0.001310172
0.11032268
9


362.1130332
-0.009603384
17884.01664
-16.23392788
0.002541599
0.014220414
9


362.4537589
0.004774992
17948.11168
86.82277459
0.002219716
0.000346881
10


360.4861797
-0.033102583
14929.18175
-30.84452397
0.002219825
0.000404354
10


358.6382289
-0.028423561
13268.46278
-27.72950817
0.00221997
0.000473142
10


357.2304768
-0.02438991
12194.22824
-18.15947438
0.00222015
0.000556153
10


356.4330087
-0.008169779
11495.86992
-8.621806364
0.00222038
0.000657343
10


356.0182099
-0.009758736
10957.41406
-10.03130092
0.002220691
0.000782214
10


355.846049
-0.002704126
10481.66979
-0.71428435
0.002221109
0.000938664
10


355.7989276
0.00182447
10151.41159
-3.584484876
0.002221684
0.001138447
10


355.7820492
-0.000605059
9810.787665
-3.940115176
0.002222513
0.001399867
10


355.6510044
-0.001372932
9489.771635
-7.047168089
0.002223796
0.001753097
10


365.1639843
-0.007325483
24666.60769
-167.4591472
0.004003787
0.000410637
11


363.4189555
-0.029042867
21137.35526
-44.1262589
0.004003784
0.00041147
11


361.7973844
-0.025640341
18928.67821
-30.06259729
0.004003782
0.000412307
11


360.1569707
-0.027864248
17150.04544
-31.9610189
0.004003793
0.000413147
11


358.6535614
-0.020867489
15610.98791
-19.18569009
0.004003785
0.000413987
11


357.4473904
-0.010541334
14416.2981
-14.20753164
0.004003786
0.000414829
11


356.6848728
-0.008416044
13557.59372
-10.36728612
0.004003787
0.000415673
11


356.3000018
0.001319542
12913.51496
-7.101190757
0.004003789
0.000416519
11


356.0608057
0.001852254
12399.57296
-6.193103147
0.004003784
0.000417367
11


355.922531
-0.010983914
11948.73856
-7.193361714
0.004003804
0.000418222
11



I tried different model structures and nothing seems to help, really. Here is the code I used for fitting an ANN (furthermore I also did an extensive hyperparameter optimization using optuna).
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from copy import deepcopy
from scipy.integrate import odeint


# Set random seed for reproducibility
rnd = np.random.RandomState(MAIN.rnd_seed)
torch.manual_seed(MAIN.rnd_seed)

# Load data and kinetic parameters

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# Standardize data
mean = np.mean(stacked_data, 0, keepdims=True)
stdv = np.std(stacked_data, 0, keepdims=True)

def standardize(data):
    return {k: (x - mean) / stdv for k, x in data.items()}

stan_data = standardize(data)

# Set indexes for input (X) and intermediate (U)
x_index = ['Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4']
u_index = ['Obj1', 'Obj2']

# %% <Define ANN Model>
class ANN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hyprams):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_size = hyprams['input_size']
        self.hidden_size = hyprams['hidden_size']
        self.output_size = hyprams['output_size']
        self.activation = nn.Tanh()
        sizes = [self.input_size, *self.hidden_size, self.output_size]
        self.linears = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(i, j) for i, j in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])])

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.float()
        for linear in self.linears[:-1]:
            x = linear(x)
            x = self.activation(x)
        x = self.linears[-1](x)
        return x * 2
    
    def init_params(self):
        for linear in self.linears:
            torch.nn.init.xavier_normal_(linear.weight.data)
            torch.nn.init.zeros_(linear.bias)

# %% <Define ANN Trainer>
class ANN_trainer:
    def __init__(self, hyprams, x_index, u_index):
        self.dtype = torch.float
        self.hyprams = hyprams
        self.x_index = x_index
        self.u_index = u_index

    def fit(self, data_train, data_valid):
        f = lambda x1: np.row_stack(np.transpose(x1, axes=(2, 0, 1)))
        g = lambda x2: np.row_stack([f(x1) for x1 in x2.values()])
        data_train = torch.from_numpy(g(data_train)).type(self.dtype)
        self.x_train = data_train[:, self.x_index]
        self.y_train = data_train[:, self.u_index]
        data_valid = torch.from_numpy(g(data_valid)).type(self.dtype)
        self.x_valid = data_valid[:, self.x_index]
        self.y_valid = data_valid[:, self.u_index]

        self.hyprams['input_size'] = len(self.x_index)
        self.hyprams['output_size'] = len(self.u_index)
        
        self.ANN = ANN(self.hyprams)
        self.ANN.init_params()

        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.ANN.parameters(), lr=self.hyprams['learning_rate'])
        self.loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()

        self.training_history = np.zeros((self.hyprams['epochs'], 3))
        for epoch in range(self.hyprams['epochs']):
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            y_train_pred = self.ANN(self.x_train)
            training_loss = self.loss_fn(self.y_train, y_train_pred)
            training_loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()

            y_valid_pred = self.ANN(self.x_valid)
            validation_loss = self.loss_fn(self.y_valid, y_valid_pred)
            self.training_history[epoch, 0] = epoch
            self.training_history[epoch, 1] = training_loss
            self.training_history[epoch, 2] = validation_loss

    def parity_plot(self, y_true, y_pred, title="Parity Plot", xlabel="True Values", ylabel="Predicted Values"):
        plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
        plt.scatter(y_true, y_pred, edgecolors=(0, 0, 0))
        plt.plot([y_true.min(), y_true.max()], [y_true.min(), y_true.max()], 'k--', lw=2)
        plt.xlabel(xlabel)
        plt.ylabel(ylabel)
        plt.title(title)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()

    def fit_aggregate(self, data_trainval):
        self.aggregate_ANN = []
        training_history = []
        for k in data_trainval.keys():
            data_train = {i: x for i, x in data_trainval.items() if i != k}
            data_valid = {k: data_trainval[k]}
            self.fit(data_train, data_valid)
            self.aggregate_ANN.append(deepcopy(self.ANN))
            training_history.append(self.training_history)
        self.training_history = np.mean(training_history, axis=0)

    def predict(self, x):
        y_aggregate = [ANN(x) for ANN in self.aggregate_ANN]
        y_aggregate = torch.dstack(y_aggregate)
        y_mean = torch.mean(y_aggregate, dim=2)
        y_std = torch.std(y_aggregate, dim=2)
        return y_mean, y_std

# %% <Define Hybrid Model>
class HybridModel(ANN_trainer):
    def __init__(self, hyprams, x_index, u_index):
        super().__init__(hyprams, x_index, u_index)

# %% <Train and Test Hybrid Model>
hyprams = {'hidden_size': [6], 'learning_rate': 0.003, 'epochs': 2000}
train_split = MAIN.train_test_split['train']
test_split = MAIN.train_test_split['test']

data_train = {x: stan_data[x] for x in train_split}
data_test = {x: stan_data[x] for x in test_split}

hyb_model = HybridModel(hyprams, x_index, u_index)
hyb_model.fit_aggregate(data_train)

# Parity Plot
y_mean, y_std = hyb_model.predict(hyb_model.x_valid)
hyb_model.parity_plot(hyb_model.y_valid.detach().numpy(), y_mean.detach().numpy(), title="Final Parity Plot after Prediction")

print("Finished")

```


You are only using a very small network with a single layer of 6 neurons. Have you tried increasing the number of layers and number of neurons in the layers?

Hi thanks for your comment! Yes, I also performed a very extensive hyperparameter optimization using optuna optimizing for layers, nodes within each individual layer, activation functions, dropout rate, regularization,...
do you have any other idea what could be happening here? aggregating models and data augmentation also did not help, apparently. Unless I have some major coding/understanding error somewhere.
or do I simply have too less (variant) data? How would I test for that?
added the info to the post.

Can you add a plot of your training loss and validation loss over time?

First and foremost, it is hard to read your question. I cannot even tell if this is a classification or regression problem. And please, do us a favor and split it into paragraphs.
Despite others' comments, I'd suggest you to take a step back and start simple. As you probably notice, the code for this should-be-simple problem is getting lengthy and error-prone. Given that your goal is not about writing an ANN but drawing conclusion from data, there is no point to get things complicated.
I'd recommend:

Start with simple library and basic algorithm. Try an elementary LinearRegression from sklearn. This would give you a good benchmark to start with and to debug the code.
Use built-in code for standard tasks e.g. standardization with StandardScaler. No point to create troubles for yourself.
Slowly move to more complicated algorithms e.g. Random Forest and ANN. Again, do not waste time reinventing the wheel - use the available module in sklearn for the job.
If none of the algorithms gave fair result, the problem is with either your data or code. Remember, anything that may get wrong will get wrong.
When you are ready to go all-out, try some AutoML solutions e.g. AutoGluon instead of spending days fine-tuning.

